# Replace product of variables to zero

Tags: replacement, approximation

It seems very simple question, I wish to get rid of the higher order by product of a*b. Any help is appreciated!

```
f = a^4 + 4 a^3 b + 6 a^2 b^2 + 4 a b^3 + b^4
f /. a b -> 0
(*output*)
a^4 + 4 a^3 b + 6 a^2 b^2 + 4 a b^3 + b^4
(*I want to have*)
a^4+b^4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at FullForm, it seems this pattern will do it

```
pat0 = Times[_. , a | Power[a, _], b | Power[b, _]]
```

Examples:

```
f = a^4 + 4 a^3 b + 6 a^2 b^2 + 4 a b^3 + b^4;
f1 = 3 (a b - 2 c);
f2 = (a b - 2 c)/(c - a b)
DeleteCases[f, pat0, Infinity]
DeleteCases[f1, pat0, Infinity]
DeleteCases[f2, pat0, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can I ask one more case? it works nicely with no denominator, but with it ,(a b - 2  c )/(c - a b), it does not work.How can I do it for the denominator?

Comment: @SaesunKim added option `Infinity`. This seems to work now on the new expression you added. `Infinity` tells it to keep searching for the pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is really amazing! I really appreciate your help :D

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if your solution works on the equivalent expression `f=(a + b)^4` ?

Comment: @yarchik it will work, but need to expand first. This works: `DeleteCases[Expand[(a + b)^4], pat0, Infinity]` gives `a^4+b^4`.

Answer (score 7):

I would use an algebraic function for an algebraic operation, similar to what I did in the similar question, [Replacement rules and algebra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124941/replacement-rules-and-algebra/124945#124945):

```
PolynomialMod[f, a b]
(*  a^4 + b^4  *)
```

Works with the rational function from [a comment by the OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125496/replace-product-of-variables-to-zero/125504#comment339742_125499):

```
Block[{f = (a b - 2 c)/(c - a b)},
 PolynomialMod[f, a b]
 ]
(*  -2  *)
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing cool command! I can see that polynomialMod can be really useful!

Answer (score 6):

```
 f /. a^(_:1) b^(_:1) :> 0
```

> a^4 + b^4

Comment: `(a + b)^4 /. a^(_ : 1) b^(_ : 1) :> 0` yields the same expression...